# Simulating swimming objects (like fish) in a circular pond (in Java)

Tags: java, object, geometry

```
public class Pond {

    public static void allcreationco(){
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
        int radius = 100;
        int x = (int) (Math.random() * 2 * radius - radius);
        int ylim = (int) Math.sqrt(radius * radius - x * x);
        int y = (int) (Math.random() * 2 * ylim - ylim);
        Fish.xfishc.add((int) x);
        Fish.yfishc.add((int) y);
    }

    allcreationdir();

    }

    public static void allcreationdir(){

    for (int i = 0; i < Fish.xfishc.size(); i++){
        double radius = Math.random()*1;
        double angle = Math.random()*2*Math.PI;
        double x = Math.cos(angle)*radius + 0;
        if (x > 0){

            Fish.xfishcb1.add(true);




        }
        else {
            Fish.xfishcb1.add(false);

        }


    }
    for (int i = 0; i < Fish.yfishc.size(); i++){
        double radius = Math.random()*1;
        double angle = Math.random()*2*Math.PI;
        double x = Math.cos(angle)*radius + 0;
        if (x > 0){

            Fish.yfishcb1.add(true);




        }
        else {
            Fish.yfishcb1.add(false);

        }

    }
```

Hi, my objective is to create a simulation (no visual drawing needed, just something to easily print info about) of a circular pond with fish randomly swimming in it.  The code above is a way of initiating 100 hypothetical fish into Arraylists in the form of x and y coordinates based on a hypothetical circle with a radius of 100 (there's gotta be a better way to do this).  I would like to have each of the 100 fish be able to swim in random directions and change to new random directions every time they reach the end of the pond.  Maybe I'd like them to reproduce after a certain time, or include another fish that moves in straight lines and can eat another fish.

```
    public class Salmon extends Fish {
public static int salmonre = 0;
    public static void salmonmove(){


    for (int i = 0; i < xfishc.size(); i++){
        if (xfishcb1.get(i) == true){
            int d = xfishc.get(i);
            int e = d + 1;
            xfishc.set(i , e);

        }
        else{

            int d = xfishc.get(i);
            int e = d - 1;
            xfishc.set(i , e);
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < yfishc.size(); i++){
        if (yfishcb1.get(i) == true){
            int d = yfishc.get(i);
            int e = d + 1;
            yfishc.set(i , e);

        }
        else{
            int d = yfishc.get(i);
            int e = d - 1;
            yfishc.set(i , e);

        }

        }
    salmonre++;


    }




   }
```

I also used Boolean arraylists to randomly determine what directions the fish are supposed move in.  Please be gentle with me in your rhetoric because I'm well aware that my approaches are ridiculous.  I know it's best to use trigonometry when simulating objects and their behaviors in a circle, but for some reason, I'm not able to wrap my head around this when looking on the internet (I keep finding things more complicated that involve visual illustrations).  Could you "please" give me comprehensive answers with ideas?  I'm frustrated.

Comment: I removed your move tag and fish tag because they should not have been included

Answer (score 2):

I wasn't entirely able to figure out how you wanted your Fish class to work based on your code, but some tips:

1. In Object Oriented programming, you do not want to have a class Fish that has static methods for updating two lists containing X and Y coordinates for all the fish.

   Instead, you want an object of class Fish to represent everything about a single fish. You can then have a list of Fish objects.
2. A pair of `boolean`s is really too coarse for directions. Use a `double` instead, one for each fish (stored in the Fish instance).
3. To implement the direction changing behavior, just check whether the next move would move the fish out of the water, and if so, pick a different direction.

Here's a simple, self contained example of the above for two Fish. They start out together and in the same direction, but diverge when they hit the edge and swim in different, random directions:

```
class Fish {
    private double x, y;
    private double angle, speed;

    public Fish() {
        x = y = angle = 0;
        speed = 5;
    }

    void move() {
        // If we swim at this angle, this is where we'll end up
        double newX = x + Math.cos(angle) * speed;
        double newY = y + Math.sin(angle) * speed;

        if (isInPond(newX, newY)) {
            // That's still in the pond, go there
            x = newX;
            y = newY;
        } else {
            // That's outside the pond, change direction
            angle = Math.random() * 2 * Math.PI;
        }
    }

    public String toString() {
        return String.format(
            "Position: %.0f,%.0f. Angle: %.0f degrees.",
            x, y, angle * 180/Math.PI);
    }

    // Check whether some coordinates are within a circular pond with radius 100
    static boolean isInPond(double x, double y) {
        return Math.sqrt(x*x+y*y) < 100;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Fish nemo = new Fish();
        Fish marlin = new Fish();
        while(true) {
            nemo.move();
            marlin.move();
            System.out.println("Nemo: " + nemo);
            System.out.println("Marlin: " + marlin);
            Thread.sleep(500);
        }
    }
}
```